# Eclipse RCP Product Export : An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Tags: eclipse-rcp, pde

Hello I am exporting an Eclipse RCP Product.
I used to export without any problem before...but now I keep getting the following error messages when exporting the product.
Target has not been changed at all.
When I install new eclipse and change to a new workspace, it works fine.
but After that, it does not work.

I attached the error message..

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.apache.ant,1.9.6.v201510161327.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.build,3.9.200.v20160204-0642.

Help Please.

Comment: Note that RCP export is deprecated.  [tag:tycho] with [tag:maven] is the only supported way to build RCPs, [see here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: I was using a local target platform to export my product...so do I need to convert all my plugin projects to maven projects with tycho to make it work? isn't there any other option?

Comment: Read the tutorial I linked. No you don't need to convert the plug-ins, tycho deals with telling maven about them. No, there isn't an alternative.